# CSS show site part inside some 'frame'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to apply some visual changes (different background or text color, some animations) to content that is visible through frame that is smartphone screen

[image]

I decided to make it such way:

1. Place simple site without effects on the bottom layer
2. Place copy of site with changes upper with `position: absolute` and hide it everywhere but rectangular block in the bottom of the page that is smartphone screen.

[image]

I tried to use simple `overflow: hidden` but it doesn't work because to use it I must place site with effects inside this small frame and set postition to absolute. But this frame is absolutely positioned too! So I can't stretch my invisible layer above simple visible site.

Maybe someone has solution or maybe such things should be done other way?

```
<div class="page">
</div>
<div class="frame">
  <div class="page-copy">
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .frame {
     position: fixed;
     bottom:20px;
     right: 20px;
  }
  .page-copy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; // this positioning doesn't work because parent has position: fixed
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This is similar to creating a magnifying lens to zoom in on a particular part of the web page. You might want to take a look at this site (http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3) they also provide a tutorial on how it is done.

Comment: i don't understand why you need to use fixed position here. The phone will work on the whole website or only the text part ? it's something you can move with mouse or fixed ?

Comment: @jeff this looks similar, but if you look at solution of magnifier you'll see that this method is siutable only for images without any changes (scaling is very simple change), while I have dynamic content that need to change a lot (for ex. font family or colors), and this content must be scrollable and must match the content below..I tried to implement magnifier in this situation, but as I understood, my situation is different

Comment: @TemaniAfif phone image is just fixed in bottom right corner so I need to use `position: fixed`.This image doesn't move or anything else. Just show content (augmented or changed) inside while you scrolling the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used `clip-path` with dynamic calculating of clip-path polygon position (because fixed clip-path 'frame' is unreal).
So, I got a little bit 'heavy' (because constantly listen to scroll is always heavy) and Edge-incompatible solution, but it works pretty well in other cases.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="content-copy"></div>
<div id="phoneScreen"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#phoneScreen {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 135px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function getCoords(elem) {    
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();    
    var pos = {
        top: rect.top + window.scrollY,
        left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
        bottom: rect.top + window.scrollY + elem.clientHeight,
        right: rect.left + window.scrollX + elem.clientWidth
    };    
    return pos;
}

var contentCopy = document.getElementById("content-copy");
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var phoneCoord = getCoords(document.getElementById("phoneScreen"));
    var clipPathStr = 'polygon(' + phoneCoord.left + 'px ' + phoneCoord.top + 'px, ' + phoneCoord.right + 'px ' + phoneCoord.top + 'px, ' + phoneCoord.right + 'px ' + phoneCoord.bottom + 'px, ' + phoneCoord.left + 'px ' + phoneCoord.bottom + 'px)';
    contentCopy.style.clipPath = "";
    contentCopy.style.clipPath = clipPathStr;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Copying the whole site is a pretty crazy thing to do and will probably cause a lot of problems. Anyway!

What happens now is that you just see the top-left corner of the website inside the phone, right? Say the phone is at x:100 and y:100. In that case you should move the copy of the website the same distance back: `top: -100px; left: -100px`. Do this dynamically as the phone moves around and it will match up.

You could also use `clip-path` to hide the parts of the website that aren't under the phone. Again, you'd need to change this dynamically as the phone moves around.

If you can achieve the effect you want using `mix-blend-mode`, you won't have to copy the whole website and everything will be much simpler.

Comment: So what can you recommend instead of copying whole site content to achieve effect when content part visible inside phone screen looks a little different? Blend modes don't help me with font-family changes or adding some animations. `clip-path` is variant but has poor browser support :(

Comment: To change fonts you'll have to do it the crazy way. I'm not saying you shouldn't, it's a nice idea. clip-path still needs a copy of the page but it might be simpler. If you can just copy part of the page, even better.